# Hidden drop down is not displaying when i press back in chrome

Tags: html, css, jsp

I have 2 drop down, based on first the second will appear and based on 2 drop down selection it will take it to the page mentioned.

**Code:**

```
<html>
<style type="text/css">
    #navMenu {
        margin: 70px;
        padding: 40px;
             }
    #navMenu select {
        color: #000;
        background: #CD5C5C;
        font-size: 15px;
        font-weight: bold;
        padding: 2px 10px;
        width: 200px;
        font-family:"Calibri",cursive;
        text-align:center;
             }
    .hiddenMenu {
        display: none;
                }
    .visibleMenu {
        display: inline;
                }
      </style>

           <script type="text/javascript">
              var lastDiv = "";
              function showDiv(divName) 
              {
                 if (lastDiv)
                 {
                   document.getElementById(lastDiv).className = "hiddenMenu";
                 }   
              if (divName && document.getElementById(divName)) 
                 {
                   document.getElementById(divName).className = "visibleMenu";
                   lastDiv = divName;
                 }
               }
            </script>


      <body bgcolor="#87CEFA">
      <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="navMenu">
            <select name="category" id="statename" onchange="showDiv(this.value);">
                <option value="-1"><b>--Select State--</b></option>
                <option>one</option>
                <option>two</option>
                <option>three</option>
                <option>four</option>
                <option>five</option>
                <option>six</option>
                <option>seven</option>
            </select>
            <br class="clearFloat" /></br>

            <form id="aform">
                <p id="one" class="hiddenMenu">
                    <select id="mymenu" size="1">
                        <option value="">--select--</option>
                        <option value="http://google.com">one selected</option>
                        <option value="http://google.com">two selected</option>
                    </select>
            </form>
            </p>
            <script language="javascript">
                var selectmenu=document.getElementById("mymenu")
                selectmenu.onchange=function()
                {
                   var chosenoption=this.options[this.selectedIndex]
                   if (chosenoption.value!="nothing")
                   {
                      window.open(chosenoption.value,"_parent")
                   }
                }
            </script>

     </div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Problems faced:**

- In IE6 the hidden drop down is not working
- how to make the code compatible for all browsers
- In chrome when we press back after selecting 2 drop down it moved to link, the press back in browser the second drop down is not seen.
- In chrome the when i select list the items are not seen in bold as per code.

Comment: your code is really unreadable... please format consistently and use valid html

Comment: Please copy paste this code as html file and see the output. First script is to display the 2nd dropdown based on first and the based on selection of 2nd drop down the web would opened. the problem i am facing is mentioned above

Comment: somebody tell me the solution

Answer (score 0):

IE6 problem is all over stackoverflow !
This is a stupid browser and it doesn't deserve the time working on a version that is compatible with it.

about making the code compatible with all browsers sometimes you will need to build a completely new css file just to get compatible with some browser and you will write in you html header tag something like this

```
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/masterie.css" />
    <![endif]-->
    <!--[if !lt IE 8]><!-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/master.css" />
    <!--<![endif]-->
```

Comment: This is not working. The same behavior is seen. Please help me on mentioned below.                                                           Problems faced:

->In IE6 the hidden drop down is not working
-> how to make the code compatible for all browsers
-> In chrome when we press back after selecting 2 drop down it moved to link, the press back in browser the second drop down is not seen.
->In chrome the when i select list the items are not seen in bold as per code.